# Learning about group velocity, phase velocity and particle velocity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, resource-recommendations, wavefunction, phase-velocity

I am studying quantum physics and I would like to know a bit more in detail about [group velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity), particle velocity and [phase velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity).

Can you suggest some books/online resources where I can learn the same.

Comment: Phase velocity and group velocity are concepts relevant for any wave phenomenon, not only quantum mechanics. Wikipedia gives more information http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity See also http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath210/kmath210.htm I do not think this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Well, it's a duplicate of many other questions which can be found under the [tag:resource-recommendations] tag and also linked from [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations). I can't close as a duplicate of more than one question, though, so I picked the introductory QM question because the OP asked in the context of quantum mechanics, and any decent intro QM book will treat the topic of group and phase velocity.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34214/2451 and links therein.