# Difficulties in understanding basic energy equation in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

While reading a text book about basics of Quantum Mechanics, I came across a situation in which it is said that

$E=\hbar\omega$ and also

$E = \frac12mv^2=p^2/2m$

where

$h$ Planck's constant

$\hbar=\frac{h}{2\pi}$ Planck's reduced constant

$\omega=2\pi f$ angular frequency

$m$ mass

$v$ velocity

$p$ momentum

But if I take the first definition,E=(h/2pi)*w,then

```
E=(h/2pi)*2*pi*f (because w=2*pi*f)

 = h*f

 = h*(v/λ)       (because v=fλ)

 = p*v           (de-Broglie's wave-particle duality p=h/λ )

 = mv*v          (because p=m*v, the momentum)

E = m*v^2
```

This is not same as definition $E=\frac12mv^2$.

What am I missing in the derivation above?

Comment: While the question may be based on a mistake, it is asked in good faith and is certainly answerable, so I don't see why it is off topic.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34214/2451

Answer (score 2):

The relationship
$$
v=\lambda\nu=\frac{\omega}{k}
$$
describes the [phase velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) ($v_p\neq v$) and not the [group velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) ($v_g=v$), so it should be 
$$
v_p=\frac{\omega}{k}=\frac{\hbar\omega}{\hbar k}=\frac{E}{p}=\frac{p}{2m}=\frac{v}{2}\tag{1}
$$
which does follow from the de Broglie relation ($p=h/\lambda=\hbar k$). Inserting (1) into your 3rd line gives
$$
E=pv_p=mvv_p=mv\left(\frac12v\right)=\frac12mv^2
$$

Comment: in the above derivation I used the definition"The wavelength λ of a sinusoidal waveform traveling at constant speed v is given by λ=v/f", while substituting for frequency 'f'. So 'v' is velocity not frequency.Then used the definition, momentum p = mass(m)*velocity(v). Which resulted E=m*v^2(and of course a big confusion in mind :)).

Comment: @GaneshHegde: You are correct. I've found your error though and have updated my answer.