# Energy of a photon seems to be $mv^2$, NOT $0.5mv^2$ like it should be

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

Obviously I must have made a mistake somewhere in my reasoning, but I can't see it.

Start with de Broglie:
$$ P= \frac{h}{\lambda}$$
$$ h=P \lambda $$

Substitute into Einstein's energy equation for a photon **(EDIT: read "particle" instead)** without any potential fields or whatever.

$$E = h f$$
$$E = P \lambda f$$
$$E = mv^2 $$

But since this photon **(particle)** isn't in any potential fields, I would expect its energy to be just its kinetic energy - $0.5mv^2$ - instead.

What mistake did I make?

Comment: $mv^2 = 0.5mv^2 = 0$ for a photon. I don't know what you're doing or where the $m$ is supposed to come from.

Comment: The momentum of a photon is not $mc$. Photons have $m=0$. See [If photons have no mass, how can they have momentum?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/if-photons-have-no-mass-how-can-they-have-momentum).

Comment: For photons $P\neq m v$. For any particle, $E^2 = m^2c^4 + P^2c^2$. Plug in $m=0$ for a photon and you get the correct relationship, $E=Pc$.

Comment: The full equation is $E^2 = p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4$. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence).

Comment: Note that your penultimate equation implies @SeanLake's correct result:  $E = P \lambda f = P c$, since $\lambda f = c$ for any wave.

Answer (score 1):

The energy of a photon is not dependent on its velocity - its velocity is always the same (within the same medium).

Instead, as you have written, the energy of the photon depends on its frequency, which varies inversely with its wavelength, as the product of the two is its speed, which is, again, a constant.

Comment: Duh, using a photon was boneheaded of me. My bad. But surely the same is true for any particle?

Comment: For other particles, the equation $E=hf$ doesn't necessarily apply.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't apply at all.  That's the Planck-Einstein equation for *photon energy*.

Comment: I  just found this question, which seems very similar to mine. (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34214/lambda-frac2hp-instead-of-lambda-frachp?rq=1)Here the OP states that "E=hf" applies to all particles, yet none of the answers or comments seem to call this error (?) out. Is it not the same situation?

Comment: See the [Planck-Einstein relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%E2%80%93Einstein_relation).

Comment: Good answer +1, and I would also suggest that a photons linear motion is a very small amount of energy compared to hf. So small it would only be noticed with trillions of other photons.