# Which formulae should I use when calculating the frequency of an electron given its speed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, frequency, wavelength, wave-particle-duality, phase-velocity

If I know the speed of an electron, how should I go about calculating its frequency?

For example, if the electron was travelling at $v$ $ms^{-1}$ there are two options I could take.

1. Calculate the momentum of the electron using $p=m_ev$. Then use the formula for de Broglie's wavelength to find the wavelength of the electron using $\lambda=\frac{h}{p}$. Then use the formula for wave speed, $v=f\lambda$ to get the frequency of the electron.
2. Alternatively, I could find the kinetic energy of the electron using the formula $KE=(1/2)m_ev^2$. Then substitute the kinetic energy calculated into $E=hf$ to get the frequency of the electron.

The first method doesn't give me the right answer, but the second method does. Which step of the first method is incorrect and why?

Comment: I've denoted $v$ to refer to the speed of the electron, and $f$ to refer to the frequency of the electron.

Comment: The $v$ in the formula $p=m_ev$ is different from the $v$ in $v=f \lambda$. The former denotes the _speed of particle_ in a wave and the latter denotes the _speed of the wave_

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34214/2451

Comment: Is your problem, you speak of correct answer, with very high velocities?