# Why do matter waves have superluminal phase velocites?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, reference-frames, faster-than-light, phase-velocity

Specifically why do they have $V = \frac{c}{β}$ as stated in this paper written by De Broglie: http://aflb.ensmp.fr/LDB-oeuvres/De_Broglie_Kracklauer.pdf ?

I follow the proof of “phase harmony” between the reference frames, but i’m getting confused between them and i don’t see why $V = \frac{c}{β}$

P.S i know matter waves are kind of an archaic concept, this is purely a historical exercise.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34214/2451

Comment: Matter waves are not an “archaic concept”. They have been an [experimental reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davisson–Germer_experiment) for a century.