# Why Klein-Gordon and Dirac's waves have a phase velocity of $c$?

Tags: wavefunction, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation, dispersion, phase-velocity

From De Broglie’s relations and the energy-momentum dispersion relation one finds:
$$v_p=\frac{w}{k}=\frac{E}{p}=\frac{\gamma mc^2}{\gamma mv}=\frac{c^2}{v} \tag{1}$$
Where, $v_p$ is the phase speed of the wave, $v$ is particle’s speed and $c$ is the speed of light. This equation demands $v_p$ to be bigger than the speed of light except for light itself or any particle moving with an equivalent speed.

The Klein-Gordon equation $$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{d^2 \Psi}{dt^2}-\frac{d^2 \Psi}{dx^2}+k_0^2 \Psi=0$$ however, (whose plane waves are also solutions to Dirac’s equation), admits the following plane waves solutions:
$$\Psi=e^{i(\sqrt{k^2-k_0^2}x-wt)} \tag{2}$$
Where, $k_0$ is particle's Compton wave-number. The problem here is that this solution is only true if $\frac{w}{k}=c$ as can be easily proven.

So, why is Klein-Gordon’s equation supposed to be valid for a particle having a speed lower than $c$ and simultaneously a phase velocity of $c$?.

---

PS: I'm aware that particles speed equals the wave's group velocity $v_g$, as can be found from derivating the dispersion relation relatively to $p$.
$v_g=\frac{dw}{dk}=\frac{dE}{dp}=\pm c\frac{d}{dp} \sqrt{p^2+(mc)^2}=\frac{c^2p}{E}=v$. So my question is why we have $v_p=c$ if it should be bigger that $c$ as $v=v_g < c$.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34214/2451

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#Special_relativity)

Comment: You made a mistake in your claim $\omega/k = 1$ (using natural units $c=\hbar=1$). Remember that for Klein-Gordon, $$\omega^2 = \sqrt{k^2+m^2}$$ so you immediately get:$$\omega/k > 1$$ In fact, you can check that:$$\frac{d\omega}{dk} = k/\omega$$ so everything is consistent now.