# Quantization of non-relativistic complex scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, second-quantization

I found that the taking the non-relativistic limit of the Lagrgangian for complex scalar fields gives

$$\mathcal{L} = i\dot{\psi}\psi^* -\frac{1}{2m}\nabla\psi \nabla\psi^*.\tag{1}$$

Now, when we quantise relativistic complex scalar fields, we must do so in terms of two types of creation/annihilation operators,

$$\psi(x) = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}}(b_pe^{-ipx}+c_P^\dagger e^{ipx}).\tag{2}$$

As per my understanding, the reason we need two such operators is that we are really quantising two independent fields $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ corresponding to $$\psi = \phi_1 + i\phi_2.\tag{3}$$

My question is why does this same argument not extend to the non-relativistic limit, where we quantize the complex field in terms of a single type of creation/annihilation operator:

$$\psi(x) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi^3)}a_pe^{-ipx}.\tag{4}$$

Going back to the logic above, does this mean that for non-relativistic complex scalar fields, the components of the complex field are not independent, ie., $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are somehow related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind the two ''types'' of creation/annihilation operators comes from the non-Hermiticity of $\phi$ (cf. Zee's QFT in a Nutshell, Ch. I.8.). Indeed this can also be seen as the appearance of having 2 independent real scalar fields $\phi_1, \phi_2$ as you point out. The reason that we even have 2 terms for any momentum $p$ in the Fourier expansion is because we have ''positive'' and ''negative'' Fourier modes because of the Klein-Gordon equation being ($p^2 + m^2 = 0$), $p$ being the four-momentum. (cf. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein–Gordon_equation#Solution_for_free_particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation#Solution_for_free_particle))

In the non-relativistic limit, the approximation $E \ll m$ breaks the symmetry of the K-G field and yields a field obeying Schroedinger's eq., which when expanded in modes has only ''positive'' Energy solutions ($E = \vec{p}^2/2m$) thus we have only ''positive'' Fourier modes. Which you point out as a single type of creation/annihilation operators.

Regarding quantizing the theory, canonically it corresponds to having $[\partial_0 \phi^\dagger(\vec{x}',t),\phi(\vec{x},t)] = -i\delta(x-x')$ regardless of which creation-annihilation operators we end up having in our Fourier expansion (again, cf. Zee's QFT in a Nutshell, Ch. I.8.).

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question.

1. It turns out that the corresponding Greens function for the Schrödinger action (1) is the [retarded Greens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator), which only has a pole for positive frequencies in the complex $k^0$-plane.
2. This implies that the Fourier expansion (4) for $\psi$ can not contain an antiparticle creation operator mode with negative frequency, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/735522/2451).
3. Moreover the real and imaginary parts of the complex field (3) become canonically conjugate pair (up to a $1/\sqrt{2}$ normalization), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15242/2451) Phys.SE post.
4. Interestingly, the above conclusions hold whether or not the Schrödinger field $\psi$ originates from a non-relativistic limit of a Klein-Gordon field as suggested in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32383/2451) Phys.SE post. (Although assuming such limit does indeed eliminate the negative frequency modes.)