# Why is the Klein Gordon equation of second order in time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, schroedinger-equation, klein-gordon-equation

I was wondering if there is any way to interpret the fact that the Klein Gordon equation is a 2nd order PDE in time. I mean, normally you would expect that as soon as you fix the initial wavefunction, then the evolution of your system is fixed for all further moments in time. This is true for the Schrödinger and Dirac equation but not for the Klein Gordon equation. Is there any way to see why this is still "correct"?

Comment: i think the short answer is: it is not a wave equation, but rather a field equation

Comment: For a connection between Schr. eq. and Klein-Gordon eq, see e.g. A. Zee, _QFT in a Nutshell,_ Chap. III.5, and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32383/2451) Phys.SE post plus links therein.

Comment: see also [arXiv:quant-ph/0307059](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0307059)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a major difference between Schrödinger/Dirac equations and Klein-Gordon one: the former are complex while the latter is real. But if you think of them a little, you'll also find a major similarity.

If you represent complex numbers of the form $a+ib$ [with matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers) of the form $\pmatrix{a&-b\\
b&a}$, then you can easily rewrite Schrödinger's equation like this (taking all dimensional constants equal to $1$):

$$\left\{\begin{align}
\dot R&=\hat H_RI-\hat H_I I\\
-\dot I&=\hat H_RR+\hat H_I R,
\end{align}\right.$$

where $R$ and $I$ are real and imaginary parts of the wavefunction $\psi=R+iI$, and Hamiltonian $\hat H=\hat H_R+i\hat H_I$.

Now Klein-Gordon equation can also be rewritten in this form:

$$\left\{\begin{align}
\dot\varphi&=A\\
\dot A&=\nabla^2\varphi-\mu^2\varphi.
\end{align}\right.$$

In both cases you have two simultaneous equations of the first order. In both cases you have to specify *two* initial conditions. For Schrödinger's equation they are real $R$ and imaginary $I$ parts of the wavefunction, and for Klein-Gordon equation they are $\varphi$ and $\dot\varphi$.

Answer (score 4):

In non-relativistic theories, you have
$$
\frac{\mathbf p^2}{2m}=E\to\frac{\hat{\mathbf p}^2}{2m}=\hat E
$$
which gives us the normal $\nabla^2$ and $\partial_t$ terms we find in the Schroedinger equation. When you account for relativity, the above energy-momentum relationship becomes
$$
\sqrt{\mathbf p^2c^2+m^2c^4}=E\tag{1}
$$
When you turn those into operators, you get some wonky second-derivative under the square root term:
$$
\sqrt{(-i\hbar\nabla)^2 c^2+m^2c^4}=i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}
$$
which is difficult to work with. So instead of (1), you just use
$$
\mathbf p^2c^2+m^2c^4=E^2\tag{2}
$$
as the start. This naturally leads to the second order in time.

Comment: well Dirac's eqution is relativistic but not second order in time and my question was rather: How do I have to interpret it that the inital wavefunction does no longer determine the evolution now anymore.

Comment: @XinWang The wavefunction has nothing to do with the Klein-Gordon equation. The wavefunction in quantum field theory is a collection of probability amplitudes for different configurations of the field $\phi$ obeying the Klein-Gordon equation. This wavefunction obeys a first-order equation (the Schroedinger equation).

Comment: @XinWang Dirac's equation is also linear in space as well. This is because he expanded $\nabla^2-\partial_t^2$ (what my Eq'n (2) turns out to be) to be a set of linear operators.

Comment: @KyleKanos I never doubted that this equation is non-linear.

Comment: @MarkMitchison I am interested in describing the motion of a spin 0 particle in the setting of relativistic quantum mechanics.

Comment: @XinWang Relativistic quantum mechanics = quantum field theory.

Comment: @MarkMitchison would you mind making an answer out of this, so that there is something I can refer to? - I think your comment is very different from this answer. Currently, I do not believe that RQM  = QFT

Comment: @XinWang: I don't know what you mean in your statement to me. Dirac's equation is linear: $(i\hbar\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)$. The KG-equation is not: $(\square+\mu^2)$.

Comment: @KyleKanos An operator is linear if $A(f+ \lambda g) = A(f) + \lambda A(g)$. Of course the second derivative is also linear $(f+\lambda g) '' = f'' + \lambda g''$.

Comment: @XinWang: Sorry, I often use the wrong words when coming to operators. I meant that Dirac's equation is first-order (linear) in space, rather than second order (quadratic) in space.

Comment: @KyleKanos yes, but this circumstance changes much in the initial conditions, I guess. A first order equation needs just the wavefunction at time $t=0$ to determine the evolution, for the second order equation, this is not enough.

Comment: @XinWang: I don't do QFT (though I'm familiar with the derivations enough that I could answer your query), so I could very well be wrong in this, but that sounds like a problem with *discrete* space (i.e., numerical problem) and not a continuous space issue. I don't immediately see why you'd need more than $t=0$ to solve for the time evolution.

Comment: @KyleKanos you need more than just the value of the function at $t=0$, namely, you need a derivative. The equation is second order in time, so the Cauchy problem needs two initial conditions.

Comment: @Ruslan: Of course! See, I knew it was going to be something trivial that I was overlooking.

Comment: Also, Dirac's equation exchanges being second order in the coordinates for adding degrees of freedom

Answer (score 2):

The time evolution of the wavefunction is always described by the Schroedinger equation
$$ \dot{\psi} = -i \hat{H} \psi,$$
which is linear in time. The Klein-Gordon equation is a classical relativistic equation describing the propagation of disturbances in a field $\phi$ carrying a mass $m$. This equation is second order in time, just like the majority of classical equations of motion one could think of (e.g. Newton's second law). When you quantise such a field theory, the wavefunction is now a *functional* of the field, i.e. $\psi[\phi(x)]$ describes the probability amplitude for a particular field configuration taking the values $\phi(x)$ at all possible space-time points $x$. Like always in quantum theory, the dynamical variables are represented as non-commuting operators. In this case, the field $\phi$ therefore becomes an operator $\hat{\phi}$, and the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ is expressed in terms of these field operators.