# Deriving Schrodinger equation from Klein-Gordon QFT with the definition $\psi(\textbf{x},t)\equiv \langle 0|\phi_0(\textbf{x},t)|\psi\rangle$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation

In the book "Quantum Field theory and the Standard Model" by Matthew Schwartz, [page 23-24](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=HbdEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PR7&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false), the position space wavefunction is defined as

$$\psi(x)=\langle 0|\phi(x)|\psi\rangle, \tag{2.82+2.83}$$

where $|\psi\rangle$ is any state in the Fock space. Then he uses the equations (i) $\partial_t^2\phi_0=(\nabla^2-m^2)\phi_0$ (i.e., the Klein-Gordon equation for the free massive scalar field $\phi_0(\textbf{x},t)$) and (ii) $[H,\phi_0]=-i\partial_t\phi_0$ to derive Eq. 2.85, in following 3 steps:

$$i\langle 0|\partial_t\phi_0(\textbf{x},t)|\psi\rangle=\langle 0|\int \frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{\sqrt{\textbf{p}^2+m^2}}{\sqrt{2\omega_\textbf{p}}}(a_p e^{-ip\cdot x}-a^\dagger_p e^{ip\cdot x})|\psi\rangle\\
=\langle 0|\sqrt{m^2-\nabla^2}\phi_0(\textbf{x},t)|\psi\rangle.\tag{2.85}$$

This equation is used to successfully derive the Schrodinger equation in quantum mechanics for the state $\psi(\textbf{x},t)\equiv \langle 0|\phi_0(\textbf{x},t)|\psi\rangle$.

1. The first equality follows from differentiation of $\phi_0(x)$ w.r.t $t$. How does the second equality follow from the first? *How are the inputs (i) and (ii) are utilized to derive the second equality from the first?*
2. Is it true that the operator $$i\partial_t\sim\sqrt{m^2-\nabla^2}~?$$ If yes, what is the use of doing the middle step?

Comment: For a connection between Schr. eq. and Klein-Gordon eq, see e.g. A. Zee, _QFT in a Nutshell,_ Chap. III.5, and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32383/2451) Phys.SE post plus links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I'm specifically interested in understanding the steps of Schwartz's book. In particular, how did it get the second equality from the first and at which step did he use $[H,\phi_0]=-i\partial_t\phi_0$? And also what happened to the integral over $d^3\textbf{p}$?

Comment: He utilized (ii) to derive/confirm (i), used in the first step. He then performed the momentum integral to derive the Fourier transform, the second step.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Is this momentum integral obvious? Because the RHS (2.85) has a minus sign that is not present in the definition of $\phi_0(\mathbf{x},t)$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I agree, but I don't see how the momentum integral works out. I agree $\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}} a_p e^{-ipx} = \sqrt{m^2-\nabla^2} \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}} a_p e^{-ipx} $. But the second term has a minus sign and an $e^{+ipx}$ instead of $e^{-ipx}$, which is the F.T. Do these sign differences cancel to give us $\phi_0(x,t)$ using some property of F.T.?

Comment: @CosmasZachos The mistake of this question compared to Schwartz is an extra factor of $i$ in the RHS of (2.85). In which case I don't see how the RHS of (2.85) is real; complex conjugation gives a factor of $-1$. And moreover I don't see how (2.81) and (2.85) both being real answers my question. (Sorry!)

Comment: I corrected the mistake. There is no second term. Cf. @Valter Moretti's answer, which cuts out the middleman.

Comment: Related answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/734239/226902

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(as a personal comment: I do not know why one should deal with complicated things like approximation of operators and so on when physics is evident...)

The only requirement is that

*the energy content of the state must have values very small with respect to the mass of the particle.*

In practice  the support of the ${\bf k}$-Fourier transform of $\psi({\bf x}, t)$ must be sufficiently concentrated in a set where $|{\bf p}|<< m$. In this situation we my safely approximate $p^0 \simeq \frac{{\bf p}^2}{2m} + m$ (I assume $c= \hbar=1$). In this situation
$$\psi({\bf x},t) = \langle 0|\phi_0({\bf x},t)|\psi\rangle \simeq \frac{e^{-imt}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int d^3{\bf p}  \: e^{i\left({\bf p}\cdot {\bf x} -\frac{{\bf p}^2}{2m}t\right)}\:\frac{\hat{\psi}({\bf p})}{2m}$$
Up to the factor $e^{-imt}$ that is a phase (even if time depeding) and can be omitted (actually it is responsible for Bargamann's superselection rule of mass), the obtained function *evidently* satisfies the *standard free Schroedinger equation*.

This approximation clearly does not hold for massless particles and this explains why photons do not (approximately) solve Schroedinger equation...

Comment: Nice answer. But, I think it would be worth adding that $|\psi \rangle =\int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi )^3}\psi({\bf p})a_p{}^{\dagger }|0\rangle $.

Answer (score 0):

1. The step follows just by the usual relation that the Fourier transform of $p\cdot \phi(p)$ is $\partial_x \tilde{\phi}(x)$, i.e. multiplication by the variable becomes differentiation.
2. There is no general relation between $\partial_t$ and $\sqrt{m^2-\nabla^2}$, since it is in general not even defined what $m$ is. The operators have to act on some specific given function to have any relation at all.

Comment: At which step did he use the information (i) and (ii)? @ACuriousMind

Answer (score 0):

If you can agree that the first step come from differentiation with respect to time, then the second step is simply noting that the operator $\sqrt{m^2-\boldsymbol{\nabla}^2}$ acts as $\sqrt{m^2+\textbf{p}^2}$ in momentum space. This is just a generalization of the fac that the operator $\boldsymbol{\nabla}$ simply acts as $i\textbf{p}$ in momentum space. They give the same result. So, no, there is no general relation between $\partial_t$ and $\sqrt{m^2-\boldsymbol{\nabla^2}},$ since they are independent differntial operators. The result is just a property of the Fourier transform. The end result is that,

$$i\partial_t\psi(x)=\sqrt{m^2-\boldsymbol{\nabla}^2}\,\psi(x)$$

from your definition of the position space wavefunction.

I hope this helps! Also, I hope you keep reading Schwartz. It's a fantastic book.

Comment: Your answer does not specify at which step he used (ii) $[H,\phi_0]=-i\partial_t\phi_0$. Moreover, why does the integral over $d^3\textbf{p}/(2\pi)^3$ go away? @BobKnighton

Comment: The integration over momentum went away by pulling out the spacial derivative and noticing the definition of the fourier transform of the field is what's left. Also I don't see a need for the commutator if the first step is already complete.

Comment: @BobKnighton I agree that the operator $\sqrt{m^2 - \nabla^2}$ acts as $\sqrt{m^2 + \vec p^2}$ in momentum space, but the thing its acting on is not the quantum field operator is it? Because of the minus sign in (2.85)?