# Why do quantum fields correspond to particle type instead of operator type?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, operators, field-theory

I know from the accepted answer to [What is the mathematical relationship between the wave functions of QM and the fields in QFT?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/745006/) that "the fields are operator-valued functions of space and time" and that "The fields are operators, so they act on wavefunctions."   I've also found several similar threads saying that fields in QFT are operator valued. But if that's the case, why do we have fields corresponding to the types of fundamental particles (e.g., electron field, photon field, ect.) instead of corresponding to the different operators (e.g. momentum field, position field, etc.)?

Comment: But position is not an operator in quantum field theory for the same reason that time is not an operator in quantum mechanics.

Comment: General tip: It might be ambiguous to refer to 'the accepted answer' as that could change in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just that that's where you start from in QFT. There's no great distinction between “particle type” and “operator type” to be made, you start with the particles and then you build more conventional operators like probability density, current out of them.

To take a condensed matter approach to this, you're going to have some little nanoscale circuit with quantum dots in it, or little molecules sitting in a break junction or whatever, and you want a good theoretical model to compare your experiments against. The theoretical model needs to be able to handle a bunch of electrons, I need to be able to say “if there is an electron here then there is an energy cost for that electron to be over there,” that sort of thing. Electrons are all identical particles, they obey Pauli exclusion.

In conventional QM, you might start by defining a non-interacting Hamiltonian $H$, it has eigenstates $\psi_n(\mathbf r)$ where $\mathbf r = [x, y, z]^T$ is a standard position vector. Then you add some interaction hamiltonian to this, and these functions are no longer eigenstates of the full Hamiltonian but they are still mathematically sound, they span the entire Hilbert space, and indeed you can use an “interaction picture” to speed up some calculations.

But the problem is, this only applies for one particle. If I want to handle multiple electrons, say two, I actually now need complicated constructions like$$\psi_{mn}(\mathbf r_1, \mathbf r_2) = \psi_m(\mathbf r_1) \psi_n(\mathbf r_2) -  \psi_m(\mathbf r_2) \psi_n(\mathbf r_1).$$
So we have gone from three position coordinates to six and we had to write out the anti-symmetry that creates Pauli exclusion. Now we can add our energy cost if state $m$ and $n$ are occupied, some interaction energy $\epsilon |\psi_{mn}\rangle\langle\psi_{mn}|$ or so.

Quantum field theory comes when you get sick of this complexity, and you invent new operators on a multiparticle space to handle it. The space is called Fock space, you just say “okay I have these $\psi_m$ functions describing different states $m=0,1,2,\dots$, but these are electrons and they are indistinguishable particles and you can't have more than one in any given state, so let me consider an electronic state to look like $|011001\dots\rangle$ , this bit-vector meaning that “there are 0 electrons in $\psi_0$, one in $\psi_1$, one in $\psi_2$, none in $\psi_{3,4}$, one in $\psi_5$.”

A direct implication is that formalism no longer blocks you from adding together in superposition two states with different numbers of particles. And you can use this to define the creation and annihilation operators, so $$\hat a_n = I_0\otimes I_1\otimes\dots\otimes |0_n\rangle\langle 1_n|\otimes I_{n+1}\otimes\dots$$ when you write it out looks complicated, but it has a really simple effect, it removes an electron from the $\psi_n$ state. You can even just treat all of the identity matrices in there as implicit and just write it as $|0_n\rangle\langle 1_n|$ if you like. And then there are expressions with this annihilator for any of the combinations, for example to figure out if a state $n$ is occupied we want $|1_n\rangle\langle 1_n|$ which is just $\hat a_n^\dagger \hat a_n$. So our interaction term above can be written directly as
$$\epsilon |\psi_{mn}\rangle\langle\psi_{mn}|\rightarrow \epsilon ~\hat a_n^\dagger \hat a_n~\hat a_m^\dagger \hat a_m.$$

The tricky thing is, how do we deal with extracting overall positional information, like charge distributions. We did all this work to hide all of these position coordinates, we don't want to undo it all. Dropping back to conventional QM, we can define the state $|x_0\rangle$ that has a particle at a position $x$ as $\psi(x)=\delta(x-x_0)$ with the Dirac δ-function, so we can conceptually use this to create an annihilator for a particular position.

We would express that state in our eigenbasis as $$
\begin{align}
|x_0\rangle &= \sum_n |\psi_n\rangle\langle\psi_n|x_0\rangle\\ 
&= \sum_n \psi^*_n(x_0) ~|\psi_n\rangle 
\end{align}$$
And we want this to come out of a creation operator, so the “field operator” is
$$\hat \psi\vphantom{\psi}^\dagger(\mathbf r) = \sum_n \psi^*_n(\mathbf r) \hat a_n^\dagger,$$
And with this operator we can then extract e.g. the charge density as $$\rho(\mathbf r) = -e ~\hat \psi\vphantom{\psi}^\dagger(\mathbf r)~\hat \psi(\mathbf r).$$

The first part of this argument is called “second quantization” if you want more information about it, this last term is where you have really graduated to a proper “quantum field,” we are providing the position coordinate as an argument to the field operator, and this position is quite distinct from the previous position coordinates in our Fock space which have mostly been intentionally forgotten.

So, you **eventually get the position and momentum back out**, but it is an average position, an average momentum over all of the particles, and the reason we do this is because the alternative is to have to deal with a whole bunch of position coordinates... With quantum field theory we invent a tremendous amount of machinery and then hide it “below decks” so that we can “sail” a bit more simply.

Comment: "Quantum field theory comes when you get sick of this complexity, and you invent new operators on a multiparticle space to handle it...you just say “okay I have these ψ_m
 functions describing different states m=0,1,2,…, but these are electrons and they are indistinguishable particles and you can't have more than one in any given state, so let me consider an electronic state to look like |011001…⟩, this bit-vector meaning that “there are 0 electrons in ψ0, one in ψ1, one in ψ2, none in ψ3, 4, one in ψ5.” Is that what we do with electron orbital configurations and quantum numbers in chemistry?

Comment: Sort of, yes! A lot of chemistry understanding can come just from looking at the hydrogen wavefunctions, valence electrons, add them together into sp, sp², sp³, sp³d hybrid orbitals etc. And you can roughly reason that hexagonal rings in e.g benzene, are made of sp² bonds, which leaves a bound electron perpendicular, so that those electron orbitals overlap into some circular structure that stabilizes the benzene more... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aromaticity . Stuff like that. But if you use a quantum chemistry package, it will very likely use some of these techniques to crunch the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

This is a universal point of confusion, and most good QFT texts explain this. Fields are infinite superposition assemblages  of creation and annihilation operators, acting on ***states*** in Fock space, all based on the Fock vacuum state $|0\rangle$ which has no excitations (particles).

You *must*, for starters, appreciate that operators act on states, $|\psi\rangle$ . In QM, wavefunctions are idiosyncratic coefficients of states, $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle$ expanded in a special basis of eigenstates of the operator $\hat x$, for people preferring to dress up the fundamental equations of QM as differential ones. This operator, $\hat x$, is rarely used (or written!) in QFT, and means something *entirely different* than the QM operator.

- In QFT, *x* is a mere parameter (space), blending with the time parameter into a structure more amenable to Lorentz transformations.

The oscillator operators (of an infinity of which QFT is a special economical arrangement) do not live in coordinate space as you understand it in QM. Their "position" d.o.f. corresponds to displacement from equilibrium of the coupled oscillator elements of the classical field continuum, and [only the normal mode momenta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon#One-dimensional_lattice) of such systems accord with your intuitive expectations of such. The QFT oscillators live in an *abstract, notional space*, instead. It actually pays to work in momentum space, and you may define and use momentum operators as linear superposition integrals of such oscillators.

So, typically, a particle of momentum *p* is the state $a^\dagger_p|0\rangle$ engendered by the operator $a^\dagger_p$. You may go ahead and define a [confusing](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/343516/getting-particles-from-fields-normalization-issue-or-localization-issue) wavefunction for it, but it is liable to confuse you more than it would help you appreciate how QFT produces scattering amplitudes, its primary function and aptitude.   Creation operators of different types have implicit flavor, charge, spin, etc... indices in them, generating particle excitations  amounting to electrons, or  photons, or  neutrinos, etc...

---

> The operators I've learned about in my QM course mostly seem to correspond to particular particle properties, like momentum, energy, etc.

Not quite: The *most* important operators you've learned about are the creation and annihilation operators that generate the spectrum of oscillators, at maximum remove from silly wavefunctions and Hermite polynomials and stuff. The "properties" they describe are the number of quanta of a fixed energy you pile up on a vacuum state. The central property of a particle is its very existence, turned on and off by these operators, invented by Dirac: just about the core of QM and QFT. It's all operators, really. Dedicated QFT texts are vastly superior to google and chatbot searches on "field quantization".

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I don't think I understand what you're getting at. What I'm getting, overall, from your answer is that operators act on states, and that wavefunctions aren't the best way to model particles in QFT.  And OK, fair enough, but what does that have to do with why quantum fields correspond to particle type instead of operator type?

Comment: As I indicated, different operators create different particles. In such a unique way that an operator is often identified with the particle (excitation) it creates out of the vacuum... Basically, it's *all* operators. But, then, that's also true for quantum mechanics, although not in the way that it's normally taught...

Comment: "As I indicated, different operators create different particles. In such a unique way that an operator is often identified with the particle"  Would you mind elaborating on this point, or suggest what search terms I should use to find more information about it?  The operators I've learned about in my QM course mostly seem to correspond to particular particle *properties*, like momentum, energy, etc.

Comment: @MikaylaEckelCifrese QM is a quantization of classical mechanics while QFT is a quantization of *classical field theory*.  Fields are a natural result when one is trying to make a relativistically invariant theory as special relativity tells us that time and space need to be treated on an equal footing.  In field theory this is the case because space and time are simply the domain of the fields whereas in QM this is not true because position is being treated as an operator while time is simply a parameter.

Comment: @MikaylaEckelCifrese This is a common confusion and because of it I think it is better to think of QFT not as "relativizing" QM but as quantizing classical field theory which was already classically the natural arena for relativity.

Comment: @MikaylaEckelCifres perhaps it might be simpler first to study how operator fields represent particles in a non-relativistic context. For example, I would suggest condensed matter field theory by Altland and Simons, the first two chapters cover this, and its a graduate school level textbook so you need only be familiar with the usual undergraduate quantum mechanics material to get started.

Answer (score 2):

You can and do define local momentum density and energy density operators, as well as global momentum and energy operators.

The reason we start with fields like an electron field or photon field is that  these fields allow us to construct *local* interactions. Locality is a key property of relativistic theory because in relativity non-locality is tied to acausality.