# How does the non-relativistic limit of the Klein Gordon equation simplify to become the Schrodinger equation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, schroedinger-equation, klein-gordon-equation

For the complex Klein-Gordon Lagrangian density in the non-relativistic limit, we can decompose the complex scalar field into the form $$\phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}e^{-imt}\psi.$$ When substituting the explicit form of $\phi$ into the lagrangian density, you end up with this term:

$$L=\frac{i}{2}\psi^*\dot{\psi}-
\frac{i}{2}\dot{\psi^*}\psi
+\frac{1}{2m}\dot{\psi^*}\dot{\psi}
-\frac{1}{2m}\partial_i\psi^*\partial^i\psi
-\frac{i}{2}\psi^*\partial^i\psi
-\frac{1}{2m}\dot{\psi^*}\partial^i\psi
+\frac{1}{2}\partial_i\psi^*\psi
-\frac{1}{2m}\partial_i\psi^*\dot{\psi}.$$

The dot means the time derivative. In the solutions, this was simplified so that only the last four terms remained. What I do not understand is how exactly the first four terms were cancelled out? Any tips on how to do this would be greatly appreciated! I understand this question has probably been asked before, but this exact specific issue is really confusing me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32383/2451

Answer (score 4):

You need to keep the $c^2$'s --- particularly  in $e^{-imc^2 t}$. Let's set $\hbar=1$ for convenience, and start from the KG equation:
$$
\frac 1{c^2} \frac {\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2}- \frac {\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}+m^2c^2 \phi=0.
$$
Write
$$
\phi(x,t) = \psi(x,t) e^{-imc^2t}
$$
where $\psi$ is slowly varying in $t$ compared to the  $e^{-imc^2t}$ factor. Then you get
$$
\left(- m^2c^2 \psi - 2i m   \dot \psi + \frac 1 {c^2}\ddot \psi- \frac {\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}+m^2c^2 \psi\right)e^{-imc^2 t}=0.
$$
Which is equivalent to
$$
i\dot \psi - \frac 1 {2m c^2}\ddot \psi= -\frac 1 {2m}  \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}.
$$
The non-relativistic limit ignores the $(1/2m c^2)\ddot \psi$ as being very small compared to the other terms.